# Discrete Wavelet transformation in R

Tags: r, matlab

I want to apply discrete wavelet transformation on image(256*256) using "Haar" wavelet to decompose it with level one. My target is to calculate wavelet co occurrence features(mainly Contrast feature)using decomposed wavelet coefficients(Approximate,Horizontal,Vertical,Diagonal). I did this work using MATLAB dwt2 function. But i want to do this using R open source software. Unfortunately the R wavelet packages and image processing packages are very complex than matlab(couldn't identify the functions clearly). I want to know how do image processing and wavelet operations in R clearly.

This is my MATLAB code for my work.

```
% read the input image
im_in = imread('D:\result\s.jpg');

%convert the input image to suitable format
im_in=imconvert(im_in);

%im2double rescale pixel values to [0 1]
imgray_in = im2double(im_in);

Apply discrete wavelet transformation using haar wavelet level 1 decomposition

[cA cH cV cD]=dwt2(imgray_in,'haar');

Use wavelet coefficients to calculate contrast feature of image

C_LL=w_c(cA);
C_HL=w_c(cH);
C_LH=w_c(cV);
C_HH=w_c(cD);
```

Contrast function

```
% Calculate the wavelet Contrast feature values 
function y=w_c(cC)
s = size(cC);

[c,r] = meshgrid(1:s(1),1:s(2));
r = r(:);
c = c(:);
y= sum(((r-c).^2).*cC(:));
```

Comment: I'd love to upvote a DWT question involving R, but you really need to include a bit more here.  There are many classes of DWT algorithms.  Which are you wanting to use?

Comment: dwt.2d haar wavelet one level transformation with package "wavelets" or "waveslim".i don't know which one is most suitable.

Comment: Have you made any attempts with either package?  If so, edit your question to say what you have tried.  Please include code!

Comment: actually not yet in r.But i did my work in matlab environment.I want to do it in r.In matlab,                                              % read the input image
im_in = imread('D:\result\s.jpg');

Comment: i did this in matlab environment.i will attach matlab code for my work in question. i didn't do it in r.

Comment: i want to know how to do this in  r?thanks!

Comment: I saw that yesterday, retracted the downvote and voted to reopen.  One other person has agreed to reopen so far, so wait and see.  If it doesn't get reopened in a day or two, try editing it again with more details.